# Memory Problem when creating large Access reports

Tags: ms-access, reporting

We are having a problem. We have a complex Access 2003 application. When our main user is trying to create a particularly long report he getting a message “2004 - There isn't enough memory to perform this operation. Close unneeded programs and try the operation again”. The problem is the rest of us are able to run the same report fine. Our user is able to run the same report ok with fewer amounts of data. We looked at the obvious things such as the amount of memory on his machine and the disk space available. That seems to be ok compared to those of are able to run ok.

The failure occurs when he tries to write the report to a word file. He is able to create the report when he writes directly to a printer, but since the report is so long what we do is to write the output to a pdf file.

The report runs 4500 pages. These are oversize pages meaning that the data would be truncated if you use a normal size printer and page. 
I have search the internet but none of the suggestions seem to work for us. Any suggestions you have will be appreciated.

Bob Avallone

Comment: Does it work if you use a pdf printer driver instead of writing it to word?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have graphics on the report?  Even a small one on the page header?  If so don't use the format event to fill the graphic.  Or change the grapic to a BMP.